# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having an issue with the warning "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given", I'm trying to display content from a database and it seems to be working fine except for this warning. I've tried a lot of methods to fix this but it does not seem to be working. The warning tells me that the line with the problem is "if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {", hope you can help me shed some light on this. Thanks.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `type`, `size`, `url`, `owner`, `created` FROM `files`";
$result = $db->query($sql);
if($result) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        echo "You have not uploaded any files.";
    } else {
        echo "  <table width='100%'>";
        echo "
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>Size</td>
      <td>URL</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>Created</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>";
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "
    <tr>
      <td>{$row['name']}</td>
      <td>{$row['type']}</td>
      <td>{$row['size']}</td>
      <td>{$row['url']}</td>
      <td>{$row['owner']}</td>
      <td>{$row['created']}</td>
      <td><a href='file?id={$row['id']}'>Download</a></td>
    </tr>";
        }
        echo "
  </table>
";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `mysqli` with `PDO`

if you want to count the rows in `PDO` do this:

```
if($result->rowCount() === 0)
```

[**PDOStatement::rowCount**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: it will now work that way, because $result is not the PDO object? i guess. not sure.

Comment: because pdo and myqli are different extensions you cannot mix them.To use any mysqli function you need a mysqli connection

Comment: This fixes the error however it now displays the "You have not uploaded any files." echo rather than the contents of the else statement.

Comment: @joedm just reverse the condition. either just put `<=0` of no rows found, or put the fetch inside the if block

Comment: @joedm I got this mistake from you , you should compare with equal see update

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help, saved me from more hours of searching!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing object and procedural style of mysqli. Try this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
```

Comment: Hello, I'm now getting Undefined property: PDOStatement::$num_rows.

Comment: Okay, didn't notice the PDO. You can't mix mysqli and PDO. See the other answers for a PDO solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use fetchColumn from select statement

```
if ($result->fetchColumn() > 0)
```

Comment: Seems to have got rid of the error, however it is no longer displaying the table. It is displaying the "You have not uploaded any files." echo rather than the else statement.